# How to pass jQuery Serialize() data to another page using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My form is -

```
<div id="formInfo">
    <form action="">
      <input type="text" name="uname" value="Chris">Name</input>
      <input type="text" name="address" value="NJ">Address</input>
      <input type="text" name="contact" value="123">Contact</input>
      <button id=""type="button" class="GrayButton" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Proceed</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I want to serialize this form's data and load another page using ajax which uses these data.

My ajax script look's like this -

```
 function loadXMLDoc()
    {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("ShowAddNewProject").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    var item= $("form").serialize();
    xmlhttp.open("GET","addprojectp1.php?q="+item,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

In addprojectp1.php -

```
$qn = $_GET['q'];
echo $qn;
```

On button click i am correctly move to `addprojectp1.php` but value of $qn is spaces. I am expecting `$qn = uname=Chris&address=NJ&contact=123`. Not sure what mistake i am doing. Please help.

Comment: If you are using jQuery already, then stop messing about with native `XMLHttpRequest` implementations, and use jQuery’s `.ajax`/`.get`/`.post` instead.

Comment: Since you are using jQuery, you might be pleased to hear that jQuery provides a simple Ajax abstraction: https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/. Either way, if your URL contains `q=uname=Chris&address=NJ&contact=123`, how should the server now which parameter is which?

Comment: if you are going to the page the data is submitted to why are you using ajax at all..just set the form action to your ajax endpoint and the form method to 'post'...then all the named fields will be in the $_POST variable.. if you want to group them in $_POST['q'], rename the fields as name="q[FIELDNAME]"

Answer (score 0):

Serialize won't give you the format you want. What you can do, however, is this:

```
$qn = unserialize($_GET['q']);
```

This way, **$qn** will be an array containing the data you sent through the GET request.

You can then do this:

```
var_dump($qn);
```

to see the format of the data in the array.